# Modeliong Graph from the maze

Tags: python, file, graph, networkx

I am having a problem with modelling a graph.

I have an input text file with the following information:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For modelling as a graph i would try to map every field to a node.

Every 5 bit sequence represents a field in the maze (node in the graph).
If there is a wall to the neighbor field, you have no edge to the neighbor node.
If there is no wall, you have an edge.

```
                            Level2.B
+-+-+                      /
|  o|                 A - B
+ + +   =>  Nodes:    |   |
| | |                 D   C
+-+-+
```

Answer (score 0):

First you probably want to parse all of these things into some sort of ordered data structure (e.g. a 3-dimensional list).

After that, I would iterate through the different dimensions of the list (probably easiest to use `numpy ndarrays` and join adjacent nodes if there is no wall/floor between them.

It might help to create a class for your fields, so you can have something like:

```
class Field():
    ...
    def can_join(self, other, direction):
        if not (self.has_wall(direction) or other.has_wall(opposite(direction))):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

You could generalise to do the floor stuff by putting in floor "walls" on some cells, but no ceiling "walls".

Don't know if this helps (or is the best way), but it's how I would start.